# Upgrade of Swift Realm Braking Changes, can I change a class name or how do I solve the conflict?

Tags: ios, swift, realm

I'm updating **Realm** an iOS Swift app from `5.5.1` to `10.12.0` using Cocoa Pods.

This update have a Breaking Change `public typealias User = RLMUser` which conflicts with my own `public final class User: Object`. Refactoring to another name makes my app to crashes as `assert(object.realm != nil)` when reading this user class.

Is it because I've renamed my class and the realm database is expecting the old name from it's database? Or should I do some sort of merge when app start?

Or should I make my own branch changing the 'typealias User = RLMUser` in the Pod?

Comment: "Refactoring to another name makes my app to crashes" <--- sounds like you just need a [migration](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47914361/best-way-to-rename-a-class-in-realm-swift).

Comment: I would recommend you to have a facade, a protocol, which you interact with instead of the concrete Realm object. In this way, your code would be very safe to refactor without the need to deal with the underlying Realm object.

Comment: There's a pretty good answer by @Sweeper but more information is probably needed. It appears this is a Sync'd app? If that's the case, a migration will not be available. Also, the overall file structure is different when using Sync/10.x vs 5.x. Can you clarify if this is Sync'd or not? Also, you could create a new user class MyUserClass and craft some code to copy the data from the old class to the new one, so it's a 'manual' migration. There are a view other options as well.

Comment: Yes, I'm going to figure out how to do the migration or first test the override suggestion by @Sweeper . I'm not using SyncUser so a migration or an override of class name should work.

Answer (score 1):

> Is it because I've renamed my class and the realm database is expecting the old name from it's database?

Yes. You can either fix this by doing a migration as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47914361/best-way-to-rename-a-class-in-realm-swift), or you can override `_realmObjectName`:

```
class RenamedUser: Object {
    ...

    override class func _realmObjectName() -> String? {
        "User"
    }
}
```

This way, to Realm, `RenamedUser` is still called `User`, but to Swift, it's called `RenamedUser`.

Comment: Thanks Sweeper. Yes I think that your suggestions will work. I will approve your solution as soon as I have implemented it in the code :)